# Modelviewset delete method override

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have User view and when I try to delete User,  I want to delete Invite model which use same email.
How to use destroy method to delete user{id} and Invite model{id) which have same email.

**My models:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class Invite(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

**My viewset:**

```
class ActiveUserView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'delete']
    serializer_class = SomeUserSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        for user in users:
            Invite.objects.filter(email=user.email)
            invite = Invite.objects.get(email=user.email)
            invite.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need a for loop here first get the object from `get_object()` method and then remove Invite object.

```py
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_object = self.get_object()
        Invite.objects.filter(email=user_object.email).delete()
        user_object.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```